# Is it possible for a child domain and a OU in the parent domain to share the same name?

Tags: active-directory, domain, organizational-unit

> I'm adding this Q/A because I just stumbled upon this limitation
>   today, and I was not able to find any documentation about it; there
>   ***is*** an old KB article about this issue, but it's currently not
>   indexed by Google (probably because it was published years ago and
>   never updated), and the issue is never mentioned elsewhere.

---

Is it possible to create a OU in the parent domain with the same name as a child domain?
Is it possible to create a child domain with the same name as a OU in the parent domain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, **this is not possible if the OU is located at the root level in the parent domain** (there is instead no issue if the OU is located in a subtree).

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240147.

The KB article is very old and only mentions Windows 2000, but **the limitation still applies as of Windows Server 2012 R2**.

Oddly, [the official guide about Active Directory naming conventions](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909264) doesn't explicitly mention this issue: it only says that you can run into it *even after you delete the conflicting item*, due to lingering tombstoned objects.